# I wish to replace a string containing a pattern using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting

I have the following lines in a file named `ref.list`.

```
234      ./XYZ_SiteMetric_TIMESTAMP.dat

456      ./XYZ_Site_TIMESTAMP.dat
```

I need to make them:

```
234      SiteMetric

456      Site
```

I am using the following command in the script:

```
sed -i 's/\*SiteMetric\*/SiteMetric/g' ref.list

sed -i 's/\*Site\*/Site/g' ref.list
```

There are bunches of similar lines in the list file.

When I run the script using `sh -x`, there are no errors and the commands are executing. But there is no change in the file.

Note: The in the `XYZ_` part is always the same in both the lines. But the `timestamp` part is different.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for an arbitrary number of characters is `.*`. `*` just means any number of matches of the previous character or expression. That is, `.*` means any number of matches of `.`, which matches any character.

Answer (score 0):

How about a shorter solution:

```
sed -ri -e 's%[.]/XYZ_(.*)_TIMESTAMP.dat%\1%' ref.list
```

It assumes that all the input follows the pattern.

Comment: from description it looks like TIMESTAMP varies. Hardcode `TIMESTAMP` won't work.

Comment: Good spot. If I knew what the timestamp looked like (the pattern), then I could improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no `_` character in Site / SiteMetric (not sure whether it's a variable) and the pattern is static you can do that this way:

```
sed 's/\.[^_]*_//;s/_.*//;'
```

First `s` will remove `./XYZ_` part and second part will remove `_TIMESTAMP.dat` part.